# VBA Trying to Tet the Cell Alphabet Address, Not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with data that are irregularly entered like

ID, Name, Rank, Location 
0, Michael, #3,    
1, Jessie, #4, NY 
2, Brittany, #7, FL 
3, Ken, #2, CA, NY 
4, Beth, #1, CA

Assume that these are all entered in each cell (comma-separated). The problem here is that for Location, some rows have no data at all, and some have multiple data, and for those with multiple data, they use extra cells towards right.

What I am trying to do, get the alphabet address of the maximum column used in the sheet. In the example above, it should be "E" because data with ID:3 has 5 data entered. In the real program, I have no idea which row has used the most columns. 
I wrote the following macro trying to first check the maximum column used in the sheet, and use the value to get the alphabet address, but the third line is giving an error "Error 1004 “Application-defined or Object-defined error” and I am not sure what is wrong with this.

```
Dim maxColNum As String, buffer As String
maxColNum = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count  'get the max column number
buffer = Cells(1, maxColNum).Address(True, False) 'get the address 
buffer = Left(buffer, InStr(buffer, "$") - 1) 'remove row number from it
MsgBox buffer  'show it in messagebox
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxColNum` should be `Long` not `String`.  It can be a string but the string needs to be the column letter and not a string that looks like a number.

`.Columns.Count` returns a Long.

```
Dim maxColNum As Long, buffer As String
maxColNum = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count  'get the max column number
buffer = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, maxColNum).Address(True, False) 'get the address
buffer = Left(buffer, InStr(buffer, "$") - 1) 'remove row number from it
MsgBox buffer  'show it in messagebox
```

Comment: I switched them but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Thank you! That was such a basic problem and I couldn't figure it out for a while... I appreciate it! It is working great now

Comment: @MikaJones as you can see I was also wrong in my first assumption.  It took me two tries.  I spent 2 hours yesterday looking at code and data only to realize I had a [tab] in the wrong place on the output.

Comment: That happens a lot to me as well. Sometimes you look into your code to fix a bug, and it takes a day, and the next day you can fix it in a few minutes.